# How to I change this. in a constructor after the object is selected from a random array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, random, constructor

If I write it as this:

```
card01.state = 3;
console.log(card01);
```

I can change the state, however, I want to change the state of the card that is selected from the random function.

```js
class Item {
  constructor(name, state) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
  }
};
class Card extends Item {
  constructor(name, damage, state, rarity) {
    super(name, state);
    this.damage = damage;
    this.rarity = rarity;
  }
};

var collectibles = [
  card01 = new Card("card of death", 5, 1, 0),
  card02 = new Card("two towers", 5, 1, 0),
  card03 = new Card("lovers", 5, 1, 0),
];

function gachaCard() {
  let random = collectibles[Math.floor(Math.random() * collectibles.length)];
  return random
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be calling `gachaCard()` anywhere...? To do what you're asking, call that function, then set the `state` of the `Card` which is returned.

Comment: How about `random.state = 3;` after random is initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adds an argument `state` to the `gachaCard()` function, then assigns this argument to the state property of the random variable.

```
class Item {
    constructor(name, state) {
      this.name = name;
      this.state = state;
    }
  };
  class Card extends Item {
    constructor(name, damage, state, rarity) {
      super(name, state);
      this.damage = damage;
      this.rarity = rarity;
    }
  };
  
  var collectibles = [
    card01 = new Card("card of death", 5, 1, 0),
    card02 = new Card("two towers", 5, 1, 0),
    card03 = new Card("lovers", 5, 1, 0),
  ];
  
  function gachaCard(state) {
    let random = collectibles[Math.floor(Math.random() * collectibles.length)];
    random.state = state;
    return random
  }

  console.log(gachaCard(2));
```

will display this in the console

```
Card {name: 'lovers', state: 2, damage: 5, rarity: 0}
```